# Forcing IP Whitelisting Globally

Tags: mysql

We utilize a Software that when creating a new user, automatically makes their host a wildcard (%), and we have no method to change this.

Is there anyway to enforce IP Whitelisting via MySQL Globally, to only allow our companies IP to reach our server?

Comment: Tell me you don't have MySQL facing the web without a firewall in front of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact IP of the incoming MySQL users, you can do the following

Suppose the user is called `datacustomer` and the incoming user's IP is `10.200.210.252`. From what you are saying, there should be a MySQL user within `mysql.user` called `datacustomer@'%'`. You cansee that user by running this query

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user
WHERE user='datacustomer' AND host='%';
```

If one row appears, you can change the host of that user

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET host='10.200.210.252'
WHERE user='datacustomer' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You'll have to repeat these steps with every MySQL user.

Comment: I suppose that will have to do, it's unfortunate I cannot add a global host list that would override wildcard users. Thank you very much.